# string value returning null value

Tags: c++, oop

In my code when i try to print the value of result inside the function str its showing null all the time. Could some pls give a input.
It showing correct value When i tried to display the value of result inside the for loop fir each iteration.

```
string str(string s, int mid){

string result;
for(int j=0;j<=mid;j++){
    result[j]= s[j];
}
return result;
}

class Solution {
public:
string longestCommonPrefix(vector<string>& strs) {
    int min= 0, max= 0,mid = 0;
    string temp2;
    max = strs[0].length()-1;
    mid = (min + max)/2;
    string temp = str(strs[0],mid);
    int flag1 = 0,flag2 = 1;

    cout<<temp<<endl;
    while(1){
        for(int i=1;i<strs.size(); i++){
            if(strs[i].compare(0,mid+1,temp,0,mid+1)!=0){
                if(flag1 == 1)
                    return temp2;
                if(mid == 0)
                    return " ";
                max = mid;
                temp2 = temp;
                mid = (min + max)/2;
                cout<<temp<<endl;
                temp = str(strs[0],mid);
                i = 1;
            }
            if(i+1 == strs.size()){
                if(mid == max)
                    return temp;
                min = mid;
                temp2 = temp;
                mid = (min + max)/2;
                temp = str(strs[0],mid);
                i = 1;
                flag1 = 1;
            }
        }
        return " ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't resize the string using `operator[]`. You are writing out of bounds and causing undefined behavior. Use

```
result += s[j];
```

to add characters or initialize the string with the correct size

```
string result(mid, '\0');
```

or simply copy the string;

```
auto result = s.substr(0, mid + 1);
```

You could replace the function `str` by

```
string str(string s, int mid){
    return s.substr(0, mid + 1);
}
```

or even remove the function and replace each call

```
str(strs[0],mid)
```

by a call to

```
strs[0].substr(0, mid + 1)
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation.